# Return a quasiquote with no beginning parenthesis in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, expression, quote

Is there a way to return an expression using quasiquotes while still getting rid of the beginning parenthesis?

For example:

```
`(a ,(foo))
```

could return actually return

```
`a *foosvalue)
```

I realize this seems kind of random.  I'm trying to write a function in scheme that returns an expression that can then be evaluated using `eval`.  Is there a better way for returning just expressions?

Comment: Do you have an example of such an expression (that you want to `eval`)? Perhaps then it'd be easier to see how to construct it with quasiquotes.

Answer (score 1):

Quasiquoting can only return valid S-expressions.  You can return something like a symbol, but not part of a list.  You can splice multiple elements from a list into a quasiquoted region using `,@`, though.